# bash loop through 2D arrays which are side by side

Tags: bash

I have a script like this, which works fine so far;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

arr1=(
    item1
    item2
)
arr2=(
    item1
    item2
)

for ((i=0;i<${#arr1[@]};++i)); do
    echo "${arr1[i]} ${arr2[i]}"
done
```

So when I run this script, it displays the arrays side by side like this;

```
item1 item1
item2 item2
```

which is what I needed. However, as the list of arrays increases, the lines are getting out of control so I'm looking for a solution like this, which is what I tried but couldn't be successful;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("item1" "item1"
                "item2" "item2"
                )

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
done
```

but this script printed the each array on a new line like this;

```
item1
item1
item2
item2
```

My aim is to display arrays side by side just like in the first script but add the arrays in 1 array so they don't take much space and easier to keep track of.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `while ((i<${#arr[@]})); do echo "${arr[i++]} ${arr[i++]}"; done`???

Comment: selam :) `((: i<0arr: value too great for base (error token is "0arr")`

Comment: @MarryJane Did you include the curly braces in the `((i<${#arr[@]}))` part?

Comment: oh I didn't see the edited code. Now it's working! Thanks for all the help!